# haproxy NOSRV issue with redirected port

Tags: configuration, haproxy

I am attempting to catch http traffic on one port (8080) and redirect it to an internal port (12345). I have the following in my haproxy.cfg

```
frontend rest_front
   bind *:8080
   #reqadd X-Forwarded-Proto:\ http
   #reqadd X-Forwarded-Port:\ 12345

   acl host_rest hdr(host) -i mypublicserver.myhost.com

   stats uri /haproxy?stats
   acl url_blog path_beg /blog

   # figure out which one to use
   use_backend rest_cluster if host_rest

backend rest_cluster
   server rest_server_host myinternalserver.myotherhost.com:12345 check
```

When I test the connection to mypublicserver.myhost.com I see the following in the log file ...

```
Aug 10 14:18:35 myproxy haproxy[30258]: <IP_ADDRESS>:56779 [10/Aug/2017:14:18:35.309] rest_front rest_front/<NOSRV> -1/-1/-1/-1/2 503 213 - - SC-- 1/0/0/0/0 0/0 "GET /somepage.html HTTP/1.1"
```

I can't figure out why the back end is not hit. The URL I'm using is http://mypublicserver.myhost.com:8080/somepage.html which should trigger the acl.

Comment: Which mode are you using? TCP or HTTP? Also, try to remove the stats directive.

Comment: @gf_8 We're using HTTP. I'll try and add that in and remove the stats directive.

Comment: @gf_8 Our default mode is set at http ... I commented out the stats directive  and retested, still the same result.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There is no default backend to use and *rest_cluster* is used only when host_rest ACL is valid.
So any request with a HOST header not matching "mypublicserver.myhost.com" will not be routed to any backend and this results in a 503 error.
So you can either add a **default_backend** directive or drop/edit the ACL.

EDIT: if the ACL is not matching this is because it is missing the port part: 8080
Try with:

```
 acl host_rest hdr(host) -i mypublicserver.myhost.com:8080
```

Comment: Using the URL he gave should set the correct Host: header, right?

Comment: @MoEmEn The issue is when I do use a matching server/URL (http://mypublicserver.myhost.com:8080/somepage.html) there is still no backend connection, it's as if the matching condition is not picking up.

Comment: Yes the matching condition is not picking, because the host header is *mypublicserver.myhost.com:8080* and not the *mypublicserver.myhost.com* so you have to update your ACL

Comment: @gf_ not the complete URL only the *host:port* part, this what should be in the host header.   
People generally think that the port part is not included in the Host header but this only true when we use a standard port

Answer (score 0):

I faced similar issue and got 503 error with similar string in log file.
Thx to @MoEmEn I resolve it.

The main thing in answer is "**the ACL is not matching this is because it is missing the port part**"

Best for me was to write the rule where url can contain port or not.
So this is my rule for HAproxy:

```
use_backend host_rest if { req.hdr(Host),regsub(:[0-9]+$,) -i mypublicserver.myhost.com }
```

Answer (score 0):

in my case the issue was I was using SSL-Passthrough however acl hdr(host) doesnt work with pass through because it needs to terminate the request to decrypt the headers. 
so I decided to use SSL-Termination then make an SSL request to the backend servers.

reference :
https://discourse.haproxy.org/t/haproxy-not-switching-between-backends/1903/15

Answer (score 0):

for me i had to disable http check since my site return error 404 
and haproxy think it is down